Who might be watching Peter Noir according to his statement about an unexpected audience?
In Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Jeff motivates his son, Miles, to realize his potential. After this, the
Spider-Gang reaches Kingpin's penthouse:

Peni: Kingpin has a private elevator entrance...from his penthouse
to the collider below.
Peter Noir: Didn't count on having an audience.

Who might be watching Peter Noir according to his statement about an unexpected audience?

I liked your question so much that I posted the same answer twice ;-)

@Valorum spamming is one hella of a drug.

Abraham Lincoln.


The script indicates that the Spider-crew are perched very high up, watching Kingpin through the skylights of his penthouse apartment.
It's Kingpin, therefore, who wouldn't be expecting an audience rather than Spider Noir. Kingpin would expect that with great height comes great privacy.

The Spiders exit a bus. We see the WHOOSH of SPIDER-PEOPLE
swinging up to the top of a crane like a SWAT TEAM, until
looking down at the PENTHOUSE, staring into SKYLIGHTS.
PENI:
Kingpin has a private elevator
entrance from his penthouse to the
collider below.
SPIDER-MAN NOIR:
[He] Didn’t count on having an audience.

